# Extract JSON Object from Json Array into mysql 8

Tags: mysql, sql, json, mysql-8.0

[image: sample data]

["{"delivered":0,"deliveryDate":1633537686480,"toUserId":148}","{"delivered":0,"deliveryDate":1633537687590,"toUserId":226}","{"delivered":1,"deliveryDate":1633537687741,"toUserId":160}","{"delivered":0,"deliveryDate":1633537687863,"toUserId":262}","{"delivered":0,"deliveryDate":1633537688019,"toUserId":263}","{"delivered":0,"deliveryDate":1633537688174,"toUserId":264}","{"delivered":0,"deliveryDate":1633537688325,"toUserId":265}"]

I want to extract this JSON Array from the below table then further I want to extract the JSON object in which I give userId and deliveryStatus  .How can I achieve this?

**expected result**
when i give toUserid 148 and also given deliveryStatus= 0

**{{"delivered":0,"deliveryDate":1633537686480,"toUserId":148}**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`JSON_TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html#function_json-table) function to convert JSON into rows; then filter using [`->`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_json-column-path) operator:

```sql
SELECT t.id, JSON_PRETTY(j.obj)
FROM t
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(t.delivery_status, '$[*]' COLUMNS(
  obj JSON PATH '$'
)) AS j
WHERE j.obj->'$.delivered' = 0 AND j.obj->'$.toUserId' = 148
```

Comment: THANK YOU ! for your quick response .Sorry ,I have some changes into Json like ["{\"delivered\":0,\"deliveryDate\":1633537686480,\"toUserId\":148}","{\"delivered\":0,\"deliveryDate\":1633537687590,\"toUserId\":226}","{\"delivered\":1,\"deliveryDate\":1633537687741,\"toUserId\":160}","{\"delivered\":0,\"deliveryDate\":1633537687863,\"toUserId\":262}","{\"delivered\":0,\"deliveryDate\":1633537688019,\"toUserId\":263}","{\"delivered\":0,\"deliveryDate\":1633537688174,\"toUserId\":264}","{\"delivered\":0,\"deliveryDate\":1633537688325,\"toUserId\":265}"]

Comment: now how can i achieve this and I want to return just result ?

Comment: It is not difficult to change the column names in the query I posted.

Comment: No, my question is something else  I knew changing column name is not difficult but thank you !!

Comment: my question is that now I have a  JSON array but JsonObject acts as a string type, now I cannot extract data due to string type so that's my question

Comment: The `obj` in the above query has JSON datatype and you can do `JSON_EXTRACT(x.obj, '$.deliveryDate')`, `x.obj->'$.deliveryDate'` and `x.obj->>'$.deliveryDate'`